# How to identify the source of growing blocked processes on a system container (LXC/OpenVZ)

Tags: monitoring, process, performance-monitoring, system-monitoring

When the number of blocked processes grow indefinitely, how to identify exactly what are these processes.

[image]

Since I'm inside a system container (LXC/OpenVZ), I can't modify the hosts' kernel modules to use tools like [perf-tools](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools) or [bcc-tools/bpfcc-tools](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc)

---

The question [How to track newly created processes in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260162/how-to-track-newly-created-processes-in-linux) doesn't cover the scenario of system containers, and most of the answers rely on tools like `perf-tools` and `bcc-tools`.

Comment: you can start from IOWAIT

Comment: It is completely on 0% both before and after the reboot.

Comment: active sysstat and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Check `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS`**

First check if `CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS` is enable. Depending on your distro, you can run:

```
grep CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS= /boot/config-`uname -r`
```

If it's enabled, you will get the following result:

```
CONFIG_PROC_EVENTS=y
```

---

**2. If it's enabled, create the monitor**

Create a file `proc_events.c` with the content:

```c
static volatile bool need_exit = false;

static int nl_connect()
{
    int rc;
    int nl_sock;
    struct sockaddr_nl sa_nl;

    nl_sock = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_CONNECTOR);
    if (nl_sock == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }
    sa_nl.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    sa_nl.nl_groups = CN_IDX_PROC;
    sa_nl.nl_pid = getpid();
    rc = bind(nl_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sa_nl, sizeof(sa_nl));
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        close(nl_sock);
        return -1;
    }
    return nl_sock;
}

static int set_proc_ev_listen(int nl_sock, bool enable)
{
    int rc;
    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
        struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
        struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
            struct cn_msg cn_msg;
            enum proc_cn_mcast_op cn_mcast;
        };
    } nlcn_msg;

    memset(&nlcn_msg, 0, sizeof(nlcn_msg));
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_len = sizeof(nlcn_msg);
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_pid = getpid();
    nlcn_msg.nl_hdr.nlmsg_type = NLMSG_DONE;

    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.id.idx = CN_IDX_PROC;
    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.id.val = CN_VAL_PROC;
    nlcn_msg.cn_msg.len = sizeof(enum proc_cn_mcast_op);

    nlcn_msg.cn_mcast = enable ? PROC_CN_MCAST_LISTEN : PROC_CN_MCAST_IGNORE;

    rc = send(nl_sock, &nlcn_msg, sizeof(nlcn_msg), 0);
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("netlink send");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

static int handle_proc_ev(int nl_sock)
{
    int rc;
    struct __attribute__ ((aligned(NLMSG_ALIGNTO))) {
        struct nlmsghdr nl_hdr;
        struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) {
            struct cn_msg cn_msg;
            struct proc_event proc_ev;
        };
    } nlcn_msg;
    while (!need_exit) {
        rc = recv(nl_sock, &nlcn_msg, sizeof(nlcn_msg), 0);
        if (rc == 0) {
            /* shutdown? */
            return 0;
        } else if (rc == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR) continue;
            perror("netlink recv");
            return -1;
        }
        switch (nlcn_msg.proc_ev.what) {
            case PROC_EVENT_NONE:
                printf("set mcast listen ok\n");
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_FORK:
                printf("fork: parent tid=%d pid=%d -> child tid=%d pid=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.parent_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.parent_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.child_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.fork.child_tgid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_EXEC:
                printf("exec: tid=%d pid=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exec.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exec.process_tgid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_UID:
                printf("uid change: tid=%d pid=%d from %d to %d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.r.ruid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.e.euid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_GID:
                printf("gid change: tid=%d pid=%d from %d to %d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.r.rgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.id.e.egid);
                break;
            case PROC_EVENT_EXIT:
                printf("exit: tid=%d pid=%d exit_code=%d\n",
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.process_pid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.process_tgid,
                        nlcn_msg.proc_ev.event_data.exit.exit_code);
                break;
            default:
                printf("unhandled proc event\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static void on_sigint(__attribute__ ((unused)) int unused)
{
    need_exit = true;
}

int main()
{
    int nl_sock;
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;

    signal(SIGINT, &on_sigint);
    siginterrupt(SIGINT, true);
    nl_sock = nl_connect();
    if (nl_sock == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    rc = set_proc_ev_listen(nl_sock, true);
    if (rc == -1) {
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto out;
    }
    rc = handle_proc_ev(nl_sock);
    if (rc == -1) {
        rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
        goto out;
    }
    set_proc_ev_listen(nl_sock, false);
out:
    close(nl_sock);
    exit(rc);
}
```

Ensure that you can compile C programs. On Debian or Debian-based distros, like Ubuntu, run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

And compile it with:

```
gcc proc_events.c -o proc_events
```

---

**3. Run it for a few seconds**

Running it this way will output directly on terminal:

```
./proc_events
```

But you can also redirect it and run for a few seconds, in order to save its output on a file:

```
./proc_events > results_file
```

---

**4. Analise the results**

The output will be in the following format:

```
fork: parent tid=48 pid=48 -> child tid=56 pid=56
fork: parent tid=48 pid=48 -> child tid=57 pid=57
exec: tid=57 pid=57
exec: tid=56 pid=56
exit: tid=57 pid=57 exit_code=0
exit: tid=56 pid=56 exit_code=0
```

---

Credits to [@cirosantilli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/32558/ciro-santilli-%E6%96%B0%E7%96%86%E6%94%B9%E9%80%A0%E4%B8%AD%E5%BF%83996icu%E5%85%AD%E5%9B%9B%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6)

Comment: Credits to @ciro-santilli-新疆改造中心996icu六四事件